# How to add multiple push pin to map in WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, dictionary

I want to make a locator and I have a json document with over 500 elements. Each element look like:

```
{
    "lat": "52.500141",
    "longi": "13.312320",
    "_name": "Restaurant Berlin"
}
```

And now I do it in my code like this: [Link to Tutorial](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/maps-in-windows-phone-8-and-phone-toolkit-a-winning-team-part-2/)

My xaml with the map element:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="mymap" ColorMode="Light" Center="50.9727,010.2145" ZoomLevel="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-13,0,-13,-72" Width="482" CartographicMode="Road">
            <toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
                <toolkit:MapItemsControl Name="RestaurantItems">
                    <toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <toolkit:Pushpin PositionOrigin="0,0" GeoCoordinate="{Binding Coordinate}">
                                <toolkit:Pushpin.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:Pushpin">
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <Image Source="/Resources/marker.png" Stretch="Uniform" Width="150" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </toolkit:Pushpin.Template>
                            </toolkit:Pushpin>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:MapItemsControl>
            </toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
</maps:Map>
```

And after I read the json file it looks like this:

```
       ObservableCollection<Restaurantmarker> restaurants = new ObservableCollection<Restaurantmarker>();

        for(int k = 0; k < JsonObjects.Count; k++)
        {
            double a = double.Parse(JsonObjects[k].lat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double b = double.Parse(JsonObjects[k].longi, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            new Restaurantmarker()
            { 
                _name = JsonObjects[k]._name, 
                Coordinate = new GeoCoordinate (a,b) 
            };
        };

        ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> children = MapExtensions.GetChildren(mymap);
        var obj = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(MapItemsControl)) as MapItemsControl;

        obj.ItemsSource = restaurants;
```

And my class for Observable Collection:

```
public class Restaurantmarker
{
    public GeoCoordinate Coordinate { get; set; }

    public string _name { get; set; }
}
```

With less, only 20 elements it worked very well, but with over 500 it doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: I wait 2-3 minutes and nothing appears. And all over half a minute is not good :/

Comment: You're not telling us that you are trying to show 500+ images of size 150x100 on the Windows Phone Map control? That will probably just not work.

Comment: A few ideas to play with that might help... Perhaps only add the pins that are currently within the visible map area, (the map bounds) refreshing which pins are shown each time the bounds of the map are changed using the relevant event (when user navigates around the map). If the user zooms out too far maybe don't show any pins, but a message instead informing user that they need to zoom further in to see the pins (or you can limit how far the user can actually zoom out).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set multiple pushpins on the map, first you need to have theirs latitude and longitude information, after that you can do this:

```
    private void setPinsOnTheMap()
    {
        MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
        for (int i = 0; i < elementsList.Count; i++)
        {
            Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
            pin.GeoCoordinate = elementsList.ElementAt(i).geoLocation;

            MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay();
            overlay.GeoCoordinate = elementsList.ElementAt(i).geoLocation;
            overlay.Content = pin;

            layer.Add(overlay);
        }
        map.Layers.Add(layer);
    }
```